Yarn install fails with 'Request failed "304 Not Modified"' error for buffer-alloc-unsafe package
I'm encountering an error while trying to install packages using Yarn. When running yarn install, the process fails with the following error:
error Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/buffer-alloc-unsafe/-/buffer-alloc-unsafe-1.1.0.tgz: Request failed "304 Not Modified"


Environment:

Yarn version: 1.22.22
Operating System: macOS 14.5 (23F79)
Node.js version: v23.4.0

Full error output:
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/buffer-alloc-unsafe/-/buffer-alloc-unsafe-1.1.0.tgz: Request failed "304 Not Modified"
    at ResponseError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:696:66)
    at new ResponseError (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:802:124)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:66750:16)
    at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at module.exports.Request.onRequestResponse (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:142287:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:710:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:117:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:552:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.


What I've tried:

Clearing Yarn cache
Deleting node_modules and yarn.lock
Removed yarn from system and re install

How can I resolve this installation error and successfully install my dependencies?

Issue resolved now Seems to be a recent issue seen around India (Mumbai) region

This should fix the error, for me it worked
npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/ --global

When we say:
curl -I https://registry.npmjs.org/
Response is:
HTTP/2 200
date: Tue, 17 Dec 2024 13:59:04 GMT
content-type: application/json
cf-ray: 8f376e7a3e643fbb-BOM
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
npm-notice: This endpoint is deprecated. Use https://replicate.npmjs.com instead.
server: cloudflare
The notice says to use replicate endpoint.

This issue is coming because you are getting cached response with 304 status code from registry.
curl -I https://registry.yarnpkg.com/buffer-alloc-unsafe/-/buffer-alloc-unsafe-1.1.0.tgz

Response: HTTP/2 304  date: Tue, 17 Dec 2024 14:34:44 GMT cf-ray: 8f374701-BOM cf-cache-status: HIT access-control-allow-origin: * age: 84810 cache-control: public, max-age=300 etag: "ea39dafd86b8e0687c33f7" last-modified: Tue, 29 May 2018 23:19:49 GMT vary: Accept-Encoding server: cloudflare
If you are adding extra query params to that registry then you will get 200 response code. below you can see i am getting 200 response.
curl -I https://registry.yarnpkg.com/buffer-alloc-unsafe/-/buffer-alloc-unsafe-1.1.0.tgz?test=true

Response: HTTP/2 200  date: Tue, 17 Dec 2024 14:35:16 GMT content-type: application/octet-stream cf-ray: 8f37a3519-BOM cf-cache-status: MISS accept-ranges: bytes access-control-allow-origin: * cache-control: public, immutable, max-age=31557600 etag: "ea3998ef5bc8d687c33f7" last-modified: Tue, 29 May 2018 23:19:49 GMT vary: Accept-Encoding server: cloudflare 
For Fixing this issue you can start fetching packages from mirror registry. you can set registry using below command for npm or yarn respectively.
npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com

yarn config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com

Also, For Private Package installation you can use below set registry using below command
yarn config set '@your-scope:registry' https://registry.npmjs.org


This is fixed!
https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/bxvmmvlqzfds
You guys can revert to old now!

I got it working. First I ran this command
curl -I https://registry.npmjs.org
HTTP/2 200
date: Tue, 17 Dec 2024 16:09:35 GMT
content-type: application/json
cf-ray: 8f382daa48c14841-BOM
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
npm-notice: This endpoint is deprecated. Use https://replicate.npmjs.com instead.
server: cloudflare

So based on this output, I change the registry to
npm config set registry https://replicate.npmjs.com

Then ran this command and was able to build the project
yarn install

Hope this helps everyone!
